# Fontlink (FontLink/SystemLink in registry) Is Not Working As Expected In Window 10 x64

Tags: windows-10, windows-registry, fonts

## What I Want

I use `Consolas` as the default font of my Notepad++, but I want better appearance of Chinese and Japanese characters and symbols when using `Consolas`.

According to The [MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/globalization/mt662331.aspx), I can link multiple fonts to `Consolas` so it can display characters that it doesn't support on its own.

## The Goal

- Display Latin characters using font `Consolas`
- Display Chinese and Japanese characters using `Microsoft YaHei`
- Display symbols that `YaHei` can't handle using `Meiryo`
- Let system handle the rest characters that `Meiryo` can't display too

## Steps to Achieve The Goal

1. Add a `REG_MULTI_SZ` entry `Consolas` in `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\FontLink\SystemLink`
2. Set the value of `Consolas`:

   ```
   MSYH.TTC,Microsoft YaHei,128,96
   MSYH.TTC,Microsoft YaHei
   MEIRYO.TTC,Meiryo,128,85
   MEIRYO.TTC,Meiryo
   ```
3. Log off Windows, then log in again

## Actual Result in Windows 7

1. Latin characters (0-9,a-z,A-Z) and frequently used symbols (;:'", etc) are displayed using `Consolas`
2. Chinese and Japanese characters are displayed using `Microsoft YaHei`
3. Special symbols are displayed using `Meiryo`
4. Other characters and symbols none of fonts above supports are displayed using system defaults (idk what that is)

## Actual Result in Windows 10

1. Latin characters (0-9,a-z,A-Z) and frequently used symbols (;:'", etc) are displayed using `Consolas`
2. Chinese and Japanese characters are displayed using `Microsoft YaHei`
3. Special symbols are displayed using **`Segoe UI Symbol`**
4. Other characters and symbols none of fonts above supports are displayed using system defaults

## Additional Info

(I need 10 rep to post more links and image, so please click the image link to view the test case result screenshot and copy/paste the url text to visit the site yourself)

Here is a test trying to understand the character coverage of fonts mentioned above (and more)

#### Tool used

- Notepad: `%WINDIR%/Notepad.exe`
- BabelMap: `http://www.babelstone.co.uk/Software/BabelMap.html`
- Test string: `我风おA☃`

  ```
  我(\u6211): A character available in both Chinese and Japanese
  风(\u98ce): A Chinese only character
  お(\u304a): A Japanese only character
  A(\u0041): A Latin character
  ☃(\u2603): A unicode symbol
  ```

#### Step to Test

1. Download BabelMap, open it, then copy the test string into `Edit Buffer`
2. Select `Single Font` radio button
3. Check `Simple Rendering` checkbox
4. Select any font by click the dropbox right to the `Single Font`
5. Observe the character glyph in `Edit Buffer`
6. Setup fontlink for `Consolas` as mentioned above, log off/in to take effect
7. Open `Notepad.exe`, open `Format > Fonts` menu to set font to `Consolas`
8. Paste test string in then observe it

#### Test Result

[image: Test case result comparison]

#### Test Result Explanation

- `Microsoft YaHei` can't display the snowman symbol
- `Meiryo` don't have Chinese characters
- `Segoe UI Symbol` contains only symbols
- `Yu Gothic` is similar to `Meiryo` but looks different
- `Consolas` is designed only for Latin script.
- Text in `Notepad.exe` is displayed using 3 different fonts:

  ```
    我风お: Microsoft YaHei
    A: Consolas
    ☃: Segoe UI Symbol
  ```

  You can tell that is surely the `Segoe UI Symbol` because those snowman are very different in different fonts

  However, in this case, we expected `Notepad.exe` display those characters using fonts like this:

  ```
    我风お: Microsoft YaHei
    A: Consolas
    ☃: Meiryo
  ```

## Questions

- Why `Meiryo` we set in the fontlink registry is completely ignored?
- How to achieve The Goal in Windows 10?

Comment: Is the file `MEIRYO.TTC` missing from your Windows 10 installation?

Comment: https://shajisoft.com/shajisoft_wp/fontlink-for-cjk-on-english-windows-10/?doing_wp_cron=1542303408.5547850131988525390625

Comment: According to [one report](https://www.reddit.com/r/Windows10/comments/9qixam/1809_breaks_systemwide_font_substitution/), some font problems were resolved with [KB4476976](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4476976/windows-10-update-kb4476976). Do you have it installed?

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft has decided to remove several fonts in Windows 10 one of them being Meriyo

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/deployment/windows-10-missing-fonts

This can be confirmed by observing HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\FontLink\SystemLink

It must be there in Windows 7 by default and won't be there in Windows 10

You can install Meriyo ttc file on your machine by either of any steps

- https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/how-to-get-meiryo-ui-font-in-windows-10/25930001-0585-4892-b58e-cb668e58da5f
- https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/typography/font-list/meiryo
- or just googling Meriyo download etc.

Comment: If you ever think before posting you will noticed that if a font is not installed, none of its glyph can be displayed as what was shown in the `test result`.